# Class design for adventure game

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a small adventure and would like to know what would be the best class design for item and npc instances.

I started with a very basic class design which used inheritance (ItemInstance -> EquipmentInstance), but this doesn't worked well because I want to be more flexible for later design choices, and because I'm sure that I want lootable NPC's (e.g. small animals).

So I came up with the idea to create one base class which can hold an item instance, npc instance or both:

```
public class Instance {

    public int instanceId;

    public ItemInstance itemInstance;
    public NPCInstance npcInstance;
}
```

This way itemInstance could hold fields for quantity, weapons or equipments and of course npcInstance would hold the current health, mana and all that stuff.

But I'm not sure if this one is a good solution or if it could lead to drawbacks. Of course I'm also open for alternatives.

Thanks!

Comment: seems like a strange catch-all solution to me, where you're going to be asking 'what is this thing?' all over the place.  Having worked with some engines in the past, I prefer your first concept. Items are items, NPC's are NPC's. If you don't want e.g.small animals to be lootable, then they have an empty loot table.  Sometimes you need to resist the urge to design beyond your requirements. How much flexibility do you _really_ need?  Flexibility (complexity) always comes with an associated cost.

Comment: You may start by looking at some examples. RPG Maker is a (very) simple engine which comes along with all of the (high level) source code in Ruby form.  You can find those scripts lying around without purchasing the engine.

Comment: I would do it by checking the fields for null. Well, I really need much flexibility, for example it should also be possible to wear an NPC (e.g. racoon) as a hat and all that sort of crazy stuff. :)

Comment: right, but imo that's a poor design. You've implemented a class that is a grab bag of functionality, and now it's the consumer's responsibility to determine how to use it.  As for your example, no, you don't want to wear an NPC as a hat. You want to wear an item as a hat, and however your game manages the NPC -> item transition is up to you, but don't conflate the two concepts.  You wear items, not living creatures.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow. Please ask it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Also, rpg in this context refers to a programming language.

Comment: I asked the same question on codereview and it got closed there.

Comment: @EdS. I would also prefer inheritance. But this would also lead me to another problem when it comes to the item class (no instance). As for example I would like to have an Watering can which could be used as a tool to water plants, but also as a weapon to damage enemies, so inheritance wouldn't work here.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR: This isn't quite appropriate for CR, either.  Design questions would only be considered if there was more code, but the code here is too generic for review.

Comment: @Jamal All right then, I'll do it :P

Comment: FYI, good or bad question aside, you may prefer to ask future questions on the [game-dev stack-exchange site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

While this question is somewhat off-topic here, I'd like to point out that inheritance with **entities** is usually a design smell.

Inheritance is fundamentally about building relationships between classes with similar **behaviour**; this is where it might be worth thinking about the difference between an *entity* and an *object*.

- An *entity* is typically a representation of the **state** of something which relates back to your application's functional requirements (e.g. a "User" entity which stores information about a user).
  Entities usually don't have much behaviour because mixing state and behaviour often leads to bloated, inflexible classes which violate SRP (Single Responsibility Principle), and may require more complex "if/else" code elsewhere in order to manage them properly.
- An *object* is typically a class which encapsulates behaviour; and may or may not interact with entities or other objects.     Objects will often have some kind of internal state, but that will be state associated with behaviour, and not something that your user would think about (e.g. A list of actions for Undo/Redo, an `isInitialised` flag, or a handle to some unmanaged resource).

Consider separating out your objects and your entities;  you might find that you end up needing far fewer entities this way.   For example, instead of creating multiple classes such as `Sword`, `Gun`, `Axe`, etc.  you may end up with a single entity called `Weapon` where `"Sword", "Gun", "Axe"` are represented in data.   (Entity modelling is a very different mindset to OO modelling;  for entity modelling, it might help to think in terms of relational data instead)

Typically Inheritance is about creating classes with similar **behaviours**; often a well-designed behavioural class ends up being named after its purpose - for example, a `Gun` sounds like an entity, but a `GunDamageCalculator` sounds far more like something which might do something useful, and might even fit in a sensible hierarchy alongside an `AxeDamageCalculator` or `CandlestickDamageCalculator` etc.

To summarise - the analogy for inheritance being an **IS-A** relationship applies to *behaviour* and not *attributes*.     The reality of most software is that describing a `Cat` in terms of an `Animal` or a `Car` in terms of a `Vehicle` is often unhelpful - more often than not, entity "base classes" end up being fairly useless, and don't actually help you write your program.

Answer (score 0):

Entity base classes like Minecraft does seem to work pretty decent. Then base Item class with property Equippable

Comment: You mean like shown [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-02Pfz0VLLac/VJXz3a9dDDI/AAAAAAAAASg/-EAj79DsUwA/s1600/MinecraftEntityHierarchy.png)? This seems to be same approach as shown in my original post, just with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to try and foresee the future in your class design. But I would recommend reading up on agile development. In particular, code only for your next requirement, but refactor for every requirement. It's nearly impossible to tell in advance what the optimal class design will look like when you are so early in development.

Keeping it simple also means trying hard to make your classes reflect whatever reality you are trying to implement. In your case, I'd say Items are a property of NPC, since the carry the items around (or in them in case of small animals). Both NPC and Items may inherit Instance if you think there's a justification for every class in your system to have shared behaviour. Inheriting from Instance just to share an int property seems like overkill.

Good class design follow the [SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) principle.